# How can we set a higher version of Log4j to grails app

Tags: grails, dependencies, log4j

I have my log4j settings in my grails app with version 2.4.3. And my log4j version inside the lib folder is 1.2.17 (the compatible version of grails 2.4.3). Due to the log4j exploit issue, I need to upgrade my log4j version to 2.16.0. How can I do the necessary configurations to point my existing grails app to the latest log4j?

Comment: Log4j 1.2.x is not vulnerable to this exploit. It does not contain the feature being exploited. Only versions 2.x <= 2.15.0-rc1 need to be upgraded.

Comment: I suggest that the question either be rephrased to leave the CVE out of it and just ask how to upgrade log4j, or that the upgrade be left out of it altogether and ask a question about the CVE.  Combining the 2 will complicate getting you a true answer because most folks won't agree with "Due to the log4j exploit issue, I need to upgrade my log4j version to 2.16.0. ", for the reason @JoshuaMoore cited above.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore But still my question is not answered. Is there any way to change log4j version from grails built-in version

Comment: "Is there any way to change log4j version from grails built-in version" - Yes.  You can express a dependency on a different version in your `BuildConfig.groovy` file.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore check the web: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j, here tell is vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

In BuildConfig.groovy file, with some that following lines, you can upgrade version of log4j, into "dependences" section:

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.16.0'

compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.16.0'
```

However, when I add dependence, the old version of log4j (1.2.17) is not deleted, so I´m not sure what version is using.

Comment: I don't think this will effectively upgrade log4j in the app and I am a little suprised that it works for you.  The reason that the 1.2.17 is still there is it is an entirely different artifact with a different artifact name (log4j vs log4j-core). I would expect to have to add exclusion(s) to `BuildConfig.groovy` to upgrade log4j in the app.

Comment: because you are using 1.2.17. if you remove this jar in your war file, logs does not works

Comment: @Diego Rossi What are you putting for the mavenRepo URL? I keep getting 403 Forbidden or permanent redirect errors when adding this.

Comment: @Matt I added as it is in the first example. But it didn't work, it still takes the default version.

Comment: @DiegoRossi I understand, I think you have a good starting point and then by possibly by adding the exclusions as mentions might work. I wanted to play around with it. What does your repositories{} look like? I'm apparently missing a repo to download the 2.16.0 version.