# Upgrade log4j to last version

Tags: java, grails

I'm using grails 2.5.x and i want to update log4j

I added

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.17.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.32'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.32'
}

grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar")
}
```

when I execute grails run-app works but when I create the war file and deploy in tomcat:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: failed to invoke constructor: public org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout(java.lang.String) with arguments: [] reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Comment: Are you doing this because you believe log4j-1.2.17 is affected by the recently announced CVE?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown exactly

Comment: I _think_ the issue is with log4j 2, not 1.  Is that correct?

Comment: We have published some relevant information at https://grails.org/blog/2021-12-14-log4j2-cve.html.

Comment: A similar question has been posed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349898/how-can-we-set-a-higher-version-of-log4j-to-grails-app.