# Update log4j in Grails 2.4 results in "Could not transfer artifact from/to grailsCentral"

Tags: grails, repository, log4j2

I need to update log4j to the latest version in my Grails 2.4.2 installation.

I am indicating this in BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.17.1'
}
```

and, the repositories section is like this:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    //mavenCentral()
    
    mavenRepo 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
    mavenRepo 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
    mavenRepo 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j'
    //uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"        
}
```

I have already tried to uncomment all the repos that are commented. And I have also added the repository indicated in the Maven page (as shown).

Every time I try to build the project, it fails with this error:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact 
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:jar:2.17.1 from/to grailsCentral 
(http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Permanent Redirect (308) (Use --stacktrace 
to see the full trace)
```

The first time I tried to build, the artifacts were downloaded, and then it failed with the above error.

Running a `grails dependency-report --stacktrace` produces this result:

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:jar:2.17.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Permanent Redirect (308) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:jar:2.17.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Permanent Redirect (308)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultTestDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:588)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultTestDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultTestDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:582)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getTestDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:563)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:jar:2.17.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Permanent Redirect (308)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:jar:2.17.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Permanent Redirect (308)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Permanent Redirect (308)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 13 more
```

Any ideas? Maybe GrailsCentral changed URL?

Comment: FYI.. A similar question has been asked a few times recently (in part because of a misunderstanding about which versions of log4j are affected by the recent log4j CVE).  One of those is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349898/how-can-we-set-a-higher-version-of-log4j-to-grails-app.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I know that the version I am using is not affected by the latest CVE, but I have to update anyway. I have already seen that question you mention (and many others), but none of them are useful to me at this point.

Comment: You are attempting to resolve artifacts over http which need to be resolved over https.  Are you able to resolve from https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I didn't set that URL, that's Grails default for grailsCentral(), I guess. I did add the repository where the artifact should be located, and it actually downloaded it, but then it fails. I don't know what it is trying to do there, adding the artifact to grailsCentral? That message "Could not transfer *from/to* GrailsCentral" is deliberately ambiguous... I'm quite lost here.

Comment: "That message "Could not transfer from/to GrailsCentral" is deliberately ambiguous." - We didn't intend for it to be deliberately ambiguous.  The message is indicating that the dep could not be resolved, and there could be any number of reasons for that which we couldn't possibly guess.

Comment: " I didn't set that URL, that's Grails default for grailsCentral(), I guess" - In old versions of Grails it was, yes.  When the server started requiring https, that changed.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Ok, then, how do I change that URL? Is there some document where these changes were explained, with the appropriate solutions?

Comment: "Ok, then, how do I change that URL?" - You can specify any repository url you like, for example `mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"`.  "Is there some document where these changes were explained, with the appropriate solutions?" - There is some relevant info at https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.2/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ok, thanks. I guess I should also comment grailsCentral(), as it no longer works, then.

Comment: " I guess I should also comment grailsCentral(), as it no longer works" - You could just delete it.  It will never work in that version of Grails again unless the server is reconfigured to support http, and it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but I'm using:

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1"
```

Is that what you're trying to do?  Maybe the base version is a shorthand for that, just something to try

Comment: I don't think that will be sufficient.  The old `log4j` artifacts will still be in the transitive dependency graph (they won't be auto evicted because the artifact names are different... `log4j` vs `log4j-core` etc)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to compile with those lines, but as @JeffScottBrown says, the old artifacts are still in the project. So, now I don't know whether I am using new or old log4j, and even if I am using the new one, I don't know how to get rid of old log4j (which may not be affected by that last CVE, but it has another vulnerabilities). Frameworks should make things easier...

Comment: "I don't know how to get rid of old log4j" - You can express exclusions in your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: "Frameworks should make things easier" - The framework does make things easier.  I am sorry that this thing in particular has been difficult. Part of the problem is that there is no reliable way for the build resolution engine to automatically evict the older libraries because they have a different name than the new one. The fact that the libraries provide the same ability isn't relevant. The fact that their names are different prevents the build tool from solving the problem for you in this particular case.  I am sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown "You can express exclusions in your BuildConfig.groovy". I have done that, in the documentation is explained how to do that precisely for log4j, but it does not work, it still appears in the dependency report. I don't even think that I am using the updated log4j artifact. Is this actually possible? I am starting to think it is not. I have posted another question for removing the old log4j from the dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801702/remove-old-log4j-dependency-from-grails. But I bet that the app would not build if I got to actually remove it.

Comment: While it's annoying when the documentation isn't accurate, grails 2 has been End of Life for at least 3 years...  I can't even find the date it was EOL'd it was so long ago.  Unfortunately, grails seems to be dying overall.  Minor versions introduce breaking bugs and support is extremely limited.  I do appreciate the feedback from JSB and the remaining devs.