# Remove old log4j dependency from Grails

Tags: grails, dependencies, log4j

After having some problems to update log4j in a Grails 2.4 project (which I don't think I have accomplised yet, btw)

[Update log4j in Grails 2.4 results in "Could not transfer artifact from/to grailsCentral"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755077/update-log4j-in-grails-2-4-results-in-could-not-transfer-artifact-from-to-grail)

Now I am finding problems to get rid of the old log4j version from the dependency list.

Interestingly enough, Grails 2.4.2 documentation explains how to exclude precisely log4j from the global set:

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.2/guide/conf.html#logging

So, this is my dependency resolution section:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {   
 inherits("global") {
     excludes "grails-plugin-logging", "log4j"
 }
 log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
 checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
 legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

 repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()        
    //grailsCentral()
    //mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins'
    mavenRepo 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
    mavenRepo 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
 }

 dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1"
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1"
 }

 plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    ....
 }
}
```

However, after cleaning and building again my application, if a run a dependency-report, log4j-1.2.17 still shows there.

Even more, as I've said before, something tells that I am neither using the new version of log4j. But I don't know how to test it.

If I put this in the "excludes":

```
inherits("global") {
     excludes "grails-plugin-log4j", "grails-plugin-logging", "log4j"
}
```

Then build fails because

```
[groovyc] groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Unable to load logging class
```

which I guess it's related with the myriad of default Grails files that have this line:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
```

I am starting to think that updating log4j version is next to impossible in Grails. In my opinion, with the last CVE regarding log4j (even though this version is not affected), they should have released some document explaining how to update to the last version.

Does someone know how to do this properly?

Comment: "In my opinion, with the last CVE regarding log4j (even though this version is not affected), they should have released some document explaining how to update to the last version." - We did for versions of Grails that are affected by the CVE.  I don't think Grails 2.4 is one of them.  More information is available at https://grails.org/blog/2021-12-14-log4j2-cve.html.

Comment: No, it's not, but it's to be expected that administrations or clients that have a very old log4j installed get nervous (and log4j 1.x has its own vulnerabilities), and they want to update anyway. So, it seems that's next to impossible to do something as simple as updating log4j in Grails. I would have appreciated it if you had told me this from the beginning, at least, it would have saved me time.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this myself.  I am in progress, but it looks so far like you are missing an important piece... From the Log4J documentaion:

> Optional Components
> Log4j 2.x contains several optional components that can be included in an application.
>
> Log4j 1.x API Bridge
> If existing components use Log4j 1.x and you want to have this logging routed to Log4j 2, then remove any log4j 1.x dependencies and add the following.

[various include types are below]

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html